# QPainter width and height

Tags: qt, mobile, symbian, maemo, qpainter

Is there any chance to find out the size of the `QPainter`? I am using `QPainter` for drawing the whole graphic interface for a mobile app. The problem is that certain application overlay the window with menu which size is different for every device, thus making things nearly impossible!
Are there any possibilities to do it instead of knowing `QPainter` size?

EDIT: simple `width()` and `height()` works!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to look at the size of the QPaintDevice attached to the QPainter

```
painter->device()->width();
```